# Rails: Giving elements unique ids

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to set Jquery event handlers, but I am not sure how to endow my erb generated HTML elements with a unique id. For example: I have a series of user posts, how do I make it so each time a user creates a new post, that post has a unique id? Then how do I set it so Jquery can identify that unique ID in my event listener?

Comment: Can you post the code you've written so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily actually :), set the ID of the html element using erb, for example:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
   <div id='<%= "post_#{post.id}" %>'>
     Name: <%= post.name %>
     Body: <%= post.body %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

this way, each of your posts will be within a div that is "unique", ie. it is named with id `#post_x` where `x` is a number (`id` of your post)